# Codeigniter and Foreach in my view

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

Soooo, I have this function

```
public function playerslist()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $data = $this->db->get('skaters')->result();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('playerslist', array('data' => $data));
}
```

and what I am trying to do use a foreach in my view to return data like so

```
<?php 
    foreach($data as $row => $value){
        echo $row;
    }
?>
```

and it just returns 0...I did a

```
<?php 
    print_r($data);
?>
```

and it returned this....

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [firstname] => Steve 
    [lastname] => Stamkos 
    [position] => F 
    [team] => TBL 
    [gp2013] => 0 
    [g2013] => 0 
    [a2013] => 0 
    [pm2013] => 0 
    [pim2013] => 0 
    [ppg2013] => 0 
    [ppa2013] => 0 
    [shg2013] => 0 
    [sha2013] => 0 
    [s2013] => 0 
    [s%2013] => 0 
    [fp2013] => 0 
    [gp2012] => 82 
    [g2012] => 60 
    [a2012] => 0 
    [pm2012] => 0 
    [pim2012] => 0 
    [ppg2012] => 0 
    [ppa2012] => 0 
    [shg2012] => 0 
    [sha2012] => 0 
    [s2012] => 0 
    [s%2012] => 0 
    [fp2012] => 0 
    [gp2011] => 0 
    [g2011] => 0 
    [a2011] => 0 
    [pm2011] => 0 
    [pim2011] => 0 
    [ppg2011] => 0 
    [ppa2011] => 0 
    [shg2011] => 0 
    [sha2011] => 0 
    [s2011] => 0 
    [s%2011] => 0 
    [fp2011] => 0 
    [gp2010] => 0 
    [g2010] => 0 
    [a2010] => 0 
    [pm2010] => 0 
    [pim2010] => 0 
    [ppg2010] => 0 
    [ppa2010] => 0 
    [shg2010] => 0 
    [sha2010] => 0 
    [s2010] => 0 
    [s%2010] => 0 
    [fp2010] => 0 
) )
```

What Am I doing wrong and do I use `$data` in a foreach?

Comment: in what context was `foreach()` used? inside a function return?

Comment: the foreach was used in my view...does that answer your question?

Comment: What output do you want? The code is echoing the index of your only element i.e. 0

Comment: the id, firstname, lastname, etc.....everything inside the stdClass Object.

Comment: This page may help you learn how to iterate over arrays http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php Read the examples carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like

```
foreach($data as $key=>$row)
{
    echo $row->firstname;
}
```

Because $data is an array of rows. So in your version, $row is the **index** of the row in the array, while $value is the row itself.

Comment: Perfect...just what I am looking for.